# Check for node exists and ad if not

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

How to check for existense of node L in xmlfile and add it if not on buttonclick like this? Would it be easier to loop throuhg the file in one time, and add it where not?

```
if (Page.IsValid)
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(map));
    var component =
         doc.Descendants("Component")
        .FirstOrDefault(comp => comp.Element("Varenummer").Value.Equals(myNumber));

    component.Element("L").Value = drpLeverandørRet.SelectedItem.Value;
    component.Element("Type").Value = drpDownWTtypeRet.SelectedItem.Value;
    component.Element("Art").Value = txtRetArt.Text;
    component.Element("Bemærkning").Value = txtRetBemærkninger.Text;

    doc.Save(Server.MapPath(map));
}



 <Reservedele>
 <Component>
 <Type>Elektronik</Type>
 <Art>dyjdtjy</Art>
 <Bemærkning>tyjty</Bemærkning>
 <Varenummer>205507k</Varenummer>
 <OprettetAf>John</OprettetAf>
 <Date>27. januar 2017</Date>
 </Component>
 <Component>
 <Type>Softcare</Type>
 <Art>Dims 11</Art>
  <L>A</L>
 <Bemærkning>lasfladfa11</Bemærkning>
 <Varenummer>1</Varenummer>
 <OprettetAf>John</OprettetAf>
 <Date>21. februar 2017</Date>
 </Component>
 </Reservedele>
```

Comment: And where is `XML`?

Answer (score 0):

As you used FirstOrDefault in your code, you can use SelectSingleNode method that return the first node that matches the expression. it is more readable.

```
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//L");
if (node == null)
{
    //does not exist                
}
else
{
    //exist
}
```

Comment: Good one Saeid. Mr Mohsen